Correlate these tables dynamically (or automated)
I have a situation where I have a couple of tables (TblA and TblB) that link together to start a record.  I then have a set of tables (TblSet1_A, TblSet1_B, TblSet1_C, etc.) that hold values linked by another table, tblLink.
The tblLink has:

Key_Val: key value to find in tblSet tables
Type: determines which set of tables to look at (1 = TblSet1, 2 = TblSet2, etc.)
DataType: determines which table of a set to look at (1=_A, 2=_B or _C)
Length: max length of value (if type = 2 and <= 255 then =_B else _C)
Description: attribute description

Example TblLink entry:



Key_Val
Type
DataType
Length
Description




4
1
2
200
Item 4



This would indicate the Key_Val = 4, tblSet table is tblSet1_B, attribute name 'Key_Val 4'.
Example TblSet1_B Entry:



ID
Key_Val
Value




1
4
Value 4



If I manually go through the system and map everything, I can write a query like this.
Note: TblLink Type = 1 indicates matching with TblA.ID, Type = 2 matches with TblB.ID.
SELECT
    a.ID AS A_ID,
    a.LINKID,
    b.ID AS B_ID,  
    b.OTHER,
    (SELECT [Value] 
     FROM TblSet1_B 
     WHERE [ID] = a.ID AND [KEY_VAL] = 4) AS item_4,
    (SELECT [Value] 
     FROM TblSet2_A 
     WHERE [ID] = b.ID AND [KEY_VAL] = 7) AS item_7
FROM 
    TblA a
JOIN
    TblB b ON (a.LINKID = B.LINKID);

Output would be like (using table data not shown above, see full example link):



A_ID
LINKID
B_ID
OTHER
item_4
item_7




1
100
1
ID3
Value 4
null


2
200
2
ID4
null
50


2
200
3
ID5
null
null



Is there a way to dynamically do this mapping and build a query in SQL or Transact-SQL (T-SQL) instead of building the (SELECT) statements manually? I'm currently on MS SQL Server 2019.
Please see this dbfiddle link for a full tables and example: https://dbfiddle.uk/Atku04Bo.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

@MatBailie I don't understand your comment, I gave a minimal reproducible example with the dbfiddle, I thought it was too much to put here.

This looks like a terribly complicated design which will be very difficult for anyone else to maintain or amend. Why don't you describe the business problem you are trying to solve and design an appropriate normalised solution. This looks a bit like a one true lookup table type of design, if you haven't heard of that you should do a search for Phil Factor articles. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/when-the-fever-is-over-and-ones-work-is-done/

@SteveFord I couldn't agree more.  This is a product someone uses and I'm trying to make sense of the backend DB for them.

This can be done with dynamic SQL, using STRING_AGG to concatenate the dynamic SELECT statements.
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @selectColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @fromClause NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
SELECT a.ID AS A_ID, a.LINKID, b.ID AS B_ID, b.OTHER';

SET @fromClause = '
FROM TblA a
JOIN TblB b ON a.LINKID = b.LINKID;';

WITH LinkData AS (
    SELECT
        Key_Val,
        Type,
        DataType,
        Length,
        Description,
        'TblSet' + CAST(Type AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
        CASE DataType 
            WHEN 1 THEN '_A' 
            WHEN 2 THEN '_B' 
            ELSE '_C' END AS TblSetTable,
        CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN 'a.ID' ELSE 'b.ID' END AS IDColumn
    FROM TblLink
)
SELECT @selectColumns = STRING_AGG(
    '(SELECT [Value] FROM ' + TblSetTable + ' WHERE [ID] = ' + IDColumn + ' AND [Key_Val] = ' + CAST(Key_Val AS VARCHAR(10)) + ') AS [Item_' + CAST(Key_Val AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']',
    ', ')
FROM LinkData;

SET @sql = @sql + ', ' + @selectColumns + @fromClause;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

Output:



A_ID
LINKID
B_ID
OTHER
Item_2
Item_3
Item_4
Item_5
Item_7
Item_8
Item_9
Item_10
Item_15
Item_16
Item_17
Item_18




1
100
1
ID3
20
null
Value 4
30
null
null
null
null
Value 15
null
null
null


2
200
2
ID4
null
null
null
45
50
null
Value 9
60
Value 15_2
Value 16
null
null


2
200
3
ID5
null
null
null
45
null
null
Value 9
60
null
null
null
null



fiddle

A suggested tweak on the _B vs _C table selector logic: CASE WHEN DataType = 1 THEN '_A'  WHEN DataType = 2 AND Length <= 255 THEN '_B'  WHEN DataType = 2 AND Length > 255 THEN  '_C' END. Fiddle.

keithwalsh and @Fiddle Thank you both, this looks like exactly what I was wondering.  I don't think there is a way to do this with "pure SQL" so this is a nice approach for T-SQL.  Thanks again!
